# How to find out the records between AM and PM

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I need to find out the records between AM and PM from the below table.

[image: table1]

for eg: If I Enter START TIME AS 7.00 AM AND END TIME AS 4.00 PM, I need to get below records.

[image: output]

Start Time and End Time data is in varchar datatype with 12 hour format. How do i distinguish between AM and PM in the search criteria. Is there any inbuilt function to extract the time in 24 hour format in sql server?. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You really need to fix your database design. Do not store date and time in separate fields and do not store either of them as varchar. You also have problem with shift, even in the picture one is spelled 'day' and another one 'DAY'.

Comment: Similarly you have both empid + empname and shiftid + shiftname stored on this table, which is probably not the way to do that either

Comment: Hi JameZ, it is a sample table i have created for the demonstraion.

Comment: You have created a sample table that has problems you're trying to solve that doesn't exist in the actual table?

Comment: It doesn't have problems with Upper case and lower case of data. but the columns i mentioned here do exist in actual table. i would try to fix the design. thanks for the suggestion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Convert your fields into `time` format and then compare it.

```
SELECT CONVERT(time, '07:01 PM')
```

**[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/9eecb7db59d16c80417c72d1/1056)**

Now, you cane write your query like below

```
select * from yourtable where CONVERT(time, starttime) >= CONVERT(time, '07:00 AM') AND CONVERT(time, endtime) <= CONVERT(time, '04:00 PM')
```